# Laravel + Inertia + Vuejs: Pagination

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

When I get all the records it works:

```php
    ...

    $items = Item::all();

    return Inertia::render('Rentals/Items', ['items' => $items]
);
```

But when I try to paginate, it breaks down:

```php
    ...

    $items = Item::paginate(15);

    return Inertia::render('Rentals/Items', ['items' => $items]
);
```

I get this error:

> `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null`

Help please. What am I doing wrong? I've been stuck for days.

Comment: Standard pagination with Laravel wont work with Inertia.js. Does one of the answers here may help you?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61076083/paginate-results-with-vue-js-inertia-js-and-laravel

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Creator of Inertia.js here.

So, you can totally use the Laravel paginator with Inertia, you just need to setup your page components to be compatible.

First, make sure you're only returning the items data to the client that you actually need. You can use the new pagination [through](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/34657) method for this.

```
$items = Item::paginate(15)->through(function ($item) {
    return [
        'id' => $item->id,
        'name' => $item->name,
        // etc
    ];
});

return Inertia::render('Rentals/Items', ['items' => $items]);
```

Next, client side, you'll need a pagination component to actually display the pagination links. Here is an example component from the [Ping CRM demo app](https://github.com/inertiajs/pingcrm/blob/master/resources/js/Shared/Pagination.vue), built using Tailwind CSS.

```vue
<template>
  <div v-if="links.length > 3">
    <div class="flex flex-wrap -mb-1">
      <template v-for="(link, key) in links">
        <div v-if="link.url === null" :key="key" class="mr-1 mb-1 px-4 py-3 text-sm leading-4 text-gray-400 border rounded" v-html="link.label" />
        <inertia-link v-else :key="key" class="mr-1 mb-1 px-4 py-3 text-sm leading-4 border rounded hover:bg-white focus:border-indigo-500 focus:text-indigo-500" :class="{ 'bg-white': link.active }" :href="link.url" v-html="link.label" />
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {InertiaLink} from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";

export default {
  props: {
    links: Array,
  },
  components : {
    InertiaLink
  }
}
</script>
```

Finally, to display the items and the pagination links in your page component, use the `items.data` and `items.links` props. Something like this:

```vue
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="item in items.data" :key="item.id">
      {{ item.name }}
    </div>
    <pagination :links="items.links" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Pagination from '@/Shared/Pagination'

export default {
  components: {
    Pagination,
  },
  props: {
    items: Object,
  },
}
</script>
```

You can find a full working example of this in the [Ping CRM demo app](https://inertiajs.com/demo-application).

Comment: Hi @Jonathan with your code, when i'm compile pagination component i got `VueCompilerError: v-if/else branches must use unique keys`. I'm using vue 3

Comment: @AdiMadhava Place the `:key="key"` attribute on the same element as the `v-for` instead of its children.

Answer (score 6):

Just to keep this post updated I'm adding what works for me using vue 3, laravel 8 and inertia 0.10:

In Pagination component I must change the :key attribute just as @AdiMadhava said before, in addition I must use Link component in order to make the page links usables, so my entire `@/Shared/Pagination.vue` looks like:

```
<template>
    <div v-if="links.length > 3">
        <div class="flex flex-wrap mt-8">
            <template v-for="(link, key) in links" :key="key">
                <div
                    v-if="link.url === null"
                    class="mr-1 mb-1 px-4 py-3 text-sm leading-4 text-gray-400 border rounded"
                    v-html="link.label"
                />

                <Link
                    v-else
                    class="mr-1 mb-1 px-4 py-3 text-sm leading-4 border rounded hover:bg-white focus:border-primary focus:text-primary"
                    :class="{ 'bg-white': link.active }"
                    :href="link.url"
                    v-html="link.label"
                />
            </template>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { Link } from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";
export default defineComponent({
    components: {
        Link,
    },
    props: {
        links: Array,
    },
});
</script>
```

And it works accurately.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your backend approach:

```
$items = Item::paginate(15);
return Inertia::render('Rentals/Items', ['items' => $items]
```

From the error message you got, it's clear the issue is about how you accessed the data on the frontend.

The `id` column you tried to access is not available in `items` object, but in `items.data` array.

So your `v-for` directive should loop over `items.data`, not `items`. That way, you can get the `item`'s `id`.

Note that, on the frontend, you will need to declare `items` as an **Object** prop, not an **Array**  prop.

In the same way, you can get access to the pagination data and links through `items.links`. Here is an example:

```
// import { Link } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
<div class="px-1 pt-10">
  <Link
    v-for=" (link, index) in items.links" 
    :key="index" 
    :href="link.url"
    class="px-1 border-2"
    v-html="link.label"
  />
</div>
```